# What do you call a morphism which can be amalgamated with any other morphism

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Fix a category. Suppose you have a morphism $X\to Y$ with the property that for any morphism $X\to Z$, the diagram $Y\leftarrow X\rightarrow Z$ admits a cocone (i.e. it can be completed to a pushout diagram - I am not assuming that there is a colimit/fibre coproduct, just that there is any way to complete the diagram).

Is there a name for this property?

Comment: Is there a name for an object $A$ so that for any object $B$ we can find an object $C$ with $A \to C$ and $B \to C$? If so, your condition would be this but in the slice category under $X$. That said, I'm not familiar with a name for either construction, and it feels a bit unnatural to me. I'm excited to see if anyone else knows, though ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: I was thinking about something like this, yes (although you probably meant the coslice category). You could express this in the language of order theory, I think, by saying that $A$ is weakly comparable to every object/not orthogonal to any object, but that's a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: It seems "[coquadrable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quadrability)" is sometimes used for this property. In my thesis I use the term for a stronger property.

Comment: Some relevant terminology that is standard in model theory: if $X$ is such that any span $Y \leftarrow X \to Z$ can be completed to a commutative square (called an _amalgam_) then we call $X$ an _amalgamation base_. A category then has the [_amalgamation property_](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/amalgamation+property) if every object is an amalgamation base. Funny thing is that the situation you describe is quite common in model theory (e.g. when working in some category of structures with embeddings and $X \to Y$ is an elementary embedding), but I don't know a standard name...

Comment: @MarkKamsma: Yes, the specific example I have in mind is actually a class of embeddings of first order structures (in a class which does not have the amalgamation property).

Comment: @ZhenLin: Wouldn't coquadrability be a property of the span $Z\leftarrow X\rightarrow Y$, rather than $X\rightarrow Y$ itself?

Comment: That is how nLab defines it but Joyal (and myself) use the term differently. See Joyal's definition of "carrable" [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10238).

Comment: @ZhenLin: I see. Joyal's definition is stronger than what I have in mind (he requires an actual pushout), although the one from your thesis does work.

Comment: My definition of "quadrable" [here](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/256998) (definition 1.1.2(a)) is the same as Joyal's. I don't remember where I got the idea from but it's not original to me. (Joyal's work on tribes was already being discussed in 2015 or earlier, IIRC, but at any rate the "carrable" terminology was probably in use in the French literature much earlier...)

Comment: @ZhenLin: I must be misunderstanding something, then, since Joyal seems to require a carrable morphism to admit a fiber product with any other compatible morphism, while you only write that we can complete pullback squares (which, to my understanding, does not require the completing morphisms to be an actual limit, only a cone, just as I (co)-require).

Comment: A pullback square is precisely a commutative square where the span is a limiting cone over the cospan.